# T-SQL: Finding the closest location of an object on a map grid

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, min

I have grid showing on a map. I know your location and the location of 2 objects on the map. Objects appear where grid lines cross. Consider the world flat and not round since the area on the map is only a short distance. I want to determine which object is closest to you without using trigonometry and multiplication for performance reasons. I'm not looking for accuracy as much as just getting a ballpark indication. I should be able to determine the shortest distance between the difference in latitude and longitude from my current location. My table, Locations, looks like this:

```
ID   Latitude   Longitude
1       50         70
2       30         40
```

If my location is Latitude = 40 and Longitude = 60, then the location with ID = 1 would be closer to me.

If my location is Latitude = 30 and Longitude = 60, probably both locations are about the same distance, so just pick one.

If my location is latitude = 30 and Longitude = 50, then the location with ID = 2 would be closer.

Comment: What version of SQL do you have? If 2008 you could use geometry functions

Comment: 2008. Wouldn't geometry functions have poorer performance than just doing straight integer comparisons? My coordinates are always integers.

Comment: Yes they typically would, but would provide a much more accurate comparison than integers would - compare for example journeys between 51.5228,-0.1028 and 50.5374,-3.5173 versus 51.228,-0.1028 and 52.5374,-1.5173

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do a min of the sum of the differences.  I tried it out,and it works pretty well.

```
SELECT MIN(ABS(s.Latitude - 47) + ABS(s.Longitude - -122)), s.ID FROM Sites as s Group By ID;
```

Comment: This is what I came up with as well after posting the question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It also will regularly return the wrong answer. E.g., with my latitude=90 and my longitude 40, this will say that ID 2 is closest (60 away) when in fact ID 1 (actually 50 away rather than the 70 this returns) is.

Comment: that is not the equation for the distance between to x,y points

Comment: CodeByMoonlight: The latitudes in my app are in highly poplulated locations and not at the North or South pole. Also, the difference between any two points is at most 50 km, so bnieland's solution is more than sufficient for ballpark figures.

Comment: Blam: I wasn't looking for an accurate distance but something that gives a indication of whether a location is within the same ballpark, which at most would be 50 km. bnieland's solution does this well enough for most highly populated locations in the world.

Comment: If you do want to get speed + accuracy, what you can do is take all the results that are within r * sqrt(2) of the answer by my equation and then apply the real trig functions.  In effect, you would reduce your candidate pool and only have to check on those records within the margin of error.  This is a common practice when checking for collisions in game programming.

Answer (score 4):

You really need to use some trigonometry to get any kind of accuracy:

```
DECLARE @LocationTable TABLE(ID int, Latitude int, Longitude int)
INSERT INTO @LocationTable(ID, Latitude, Longitude)
VALUES
    (1,50,70),
    (2,30,40)

DECLARE
    @MyLatitude int = 90,
    @MyLongitude int = 40

WITH DistanceTable AS
(
    SELECT ID, Latitude, Longitude,
        SQRT(POWER(Latitude - @MyLatitude,2) + POWER(Longitude - @MyLongitude, 2)) AS Distance
    FROM @LocationTable
)
SELECT ODT.ID, ODT.Latitude, ODT.Longitude, ODT.Distance
FROM (SELECT ID, Latitude, Longitude, Distance, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Distance) AS Position
    FROM DistanceTable) AS ODT
WHERE ODT.Position = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks but I stated in the post that I wasn't looking for accuracy. If I need accuracy, then I will use the built-in geometry functions.

Comment: @AndroidDev, unless the points are near the equator, then without the trigonometry the results will be totally wrong. For example, in Moscow (latitude is 55°N) 1 degree of latitude = 111.13 km (as everywhere else), however 1 degree of longitude is just 63.7 km due to the latitude is far away from equator. So, if you're in Moscow, and there're 2 points, one 110 km to the north, another one 64 km to the West, then your method will say that 110 km is closer then the 64 km.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT MIN(((s.Latitude - @lat)*(s.Latitude - @lat)) + ((s.Longitude - @lon)*(s.Longitude - @lon))), s.ID FROM Sites as s Group By ID;