# Events in markers

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-markers

I'm working in a App to populate a MapView with a list of favorite sites. 
Now, I have all the markers in the MapView, but I would like to do a event on this markers that when I press one of them, launch another activity.

I try to do a onTouch event that get the X and Y coordinates and after this, check in the Database if this GeoPoint is, but It's imposible to check 'cos the geopoint are so accurated with a lot of decimals and It's so difficult to get the same as I have in the Database.

The question is: Are there some way to do a event in this marker???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a "list of favorite sites", assuming a modest number of sites, `ItemizedOverlay` is the typical overlay to use. If you are using that, simply override the `onTap()` that supplies the index of the particular marker that the user tapped upon.

If you are using `Overlay` instead of `ItemizedOverlay`, you can find the item in your database that is closest to the user's tapped coordinates, using something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(ABS(Latitude - ?) + ABS(Longitude - ?)), _ID FROM Sites GROUP BY _ID LIMIT 1;
```

where you supply your latitude and longitude as a two-element `String[]` to `rawQuery()` and adjust the column names as appropriate. Note that I have not tried this query personally, so there may be issues with my conversion to SQLite.

(derived from [T-SQL: Finding the closest location of an object on a map grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382915/t-sql-finding-the-closest-location-of-an-object-on-a-map-grid))

Comment: This is my onTap method in ItemizedOVerlay class:

Comment: protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  String etiqueta = mOverlays.get(index).getTitle();
  Toast.makeText(context, etiqueta,
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return true;
 }  BY NOTHING HAPPENDS WHEN I CLICKED---

Comment: Here is a sample application that supports `onTap()` and works: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk